# Prevent new line after every word in span

Tags: html, css

We are using some code to make a tooltip appear while hovering over text or an icon. Using a `transform` we are then able to center the tooltip, no matter what size it is, so we can have the size scale with the content of the tooltip: http://jsfiddle.net/z8wxdjzu/4/

```css
.position-me {
  margin: 10%;
}
.abbr {
  position: relative;
}
.tooltip {
  background: orange;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 100px;
  padding: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  right: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
}
.abbr:hover .tooltip {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="position-me">
  <span class="abbr">
    Text
    <span class="tooltip">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

The problem is that even when providing a larger maximum width, a new line is added in the tooltip after every word. Instead we want the tooltip to fill the entire width (provided with `max-width`) before moving to a second line.

We don't want to set a fixed width, because some tooltips are rather short and we don't want a lot of empty space in the tooltip. How can we prevent the line breaks from happening?

EDIT: The max-width is actually important, since some of the tooltips are long enough to span several lines, so just removing it and using a `whitespace: nowrap` is going to be insufficient, unless we do manual line breaks, which I'd rather prevent.

Comment: I modified your link, and instead of `max-width` used only `width`. It worked, try it.

Comment: In order to figure out how to make what you have done work, we need to see something of what you have done.  Please edit your question to include representative code samples.

Comment: @AleOtero93: yes, but this would not make the tooltip's width scalable and would result in a lot of empty space for shorter tooltips.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `tooltip` span wants to have it's width be less or equal to the parent's width, in this case the `span.abbr`.

So to fix it we can add another div around the `tooltip` that is a bit larger  but outside the flow of the other text, and it works.

**Edit:** I edited the snippet to center the tooltip. I also left in the red background for the surrounding div to show the trick that I apply here.

Example snippet:

```css
    .position-me {
      margin: 10%;
    }
    .abbr {
      position: relative;
    }
    .abbr div {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 50%;
      background-color: red;
      width: 200px;
      height: 2px;
    }
    .tooltip {
      background: orange;
      display: none;
      text-align: center;
      max-width: 100px;
      padding: 3px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 20px;
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
      transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    }
    .abbr:hover .tooltip {
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="position-me">
      Bla bla bla
      <span class="abbr">
        HOVER ME
        <div><span class="tooltip">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
      </div></span>
      some more text here.
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here the fixed fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z8wxdjzu/5/)

You need to remove `position:absolute` and then add `width:auto` on `.tooltip` class and add `display:inline-block;` to `.abbr:hover .tooltip`

Comment: removing the absolute position causes display problems if there is any additional text after the text with the tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent breaking (which you can do) without losing the max-width.

Just adding `white-space:nowrap` will stop the text breaking but will cause overflow of the span. So remove the max-width and all is good.

```css
.position-me {
  margin: 10%;
}
.abbr {
  position: relative;
}
.tooltip {
  background: orange;
  /*display: none; */
  /* disabled for demo */
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
.abbr:hover .tooltip {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="position-me"> <span class="abbr">
        Text
        <span class="tooltip">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i changed your css file this way and it worked !

```css
.position-me {
    margin: 10%;
}
.abbr {
    //position: relative;//notice here
}
.tooltip {
    background: orange;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    //max-width: 100px;
    padding: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    transform: translate(-100%, 200%);//notice here !!!
}
.abbr:hover .tooltip {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, removing the "position relative" from the `.abbr` class does fix the problem with the line breaks, but the positioning then becomes an issue again.

Comment: well ... it depends on the other elements of your page ! maybe if you put the complete code we can help you in a better way ...

Comment: The elements can be positioned anywhere. They are often links inside the text, but could also be icons that have functional value.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.position-me {
    margin: 10%;
}
.abbr {
    position: relative;
}

.tooltip {
    max-width: 200px;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #000000;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display:none;
}


.abbr:hover .tooltip {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="position-me"> <span class="abbr">
        Text
        <span class="tooltip">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. rerterte rtertertert</span>
</span>
</div>
```

This should be the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/z8wxdjzu/7/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I wasn't clear enough in my question about the max-width actually being important due to the possibly long tooltips that have to have line breaks after the maximum width has been reached.

Comment: I am afraid the removal of the `position: absolute` no longer makes it a tooltip, but actually involves the rest of the page as well.